# EnumDisplaySettings reports wrong values on Win7 with Nvidia cards

Tags: winapi, windows-7

I've been encountering a problem when trying to query all available resolutions on some nvidia cards under
Win7.

for(int i = 0; EnumDisplaySettings( deviceName.c_str(), i, &dm) != 0; ++i)

reports resolution which aren't available like 866 x 650.
Most supported resolutions on the other hand are missing.
Changing driver/monitor setup didn't help.
With Vista everything is fine.
[cards: FX5200, GTX295]
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @yzerman did you figure out what was the issue? Im not having hte issue but Im concerend other users of my application might. Just curious if you verified this was true or it was a mistake in your code?

Answer (score 0):

What is deviceName? You need to get the correct combination of adapter (graphics card) and monitor if you want display settings you can actually use.

Comment: the string looks like
\\.\DISPLAY2